# Customize when the mobile menu triggers in WP 6.2.1

Tags: menus, navigation, mobile, responsive

I am trying to customize when the default WordPress mobile menu triggers. It appears right now that the responsive menu kicks in at min-width: 600px. I would like it to trigger at 800px.

I was hoping there were settings in the Appearance > Themes > Template Parts to control this, but I couldn't find any.

I also tried to locate the class/id names so I could override it manually in a separate stylesheet, but it doesn't seem to have an effect:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
        .wp-block-navigation__responsive-container:not(.hidden-by-default):not(.is-menu-open) { display: none }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
        .wp-block-navigation__responsive-container:not(.hidden-by-default):not(.is-menu-open) { display: block }
}
```

Are there other methods to control when the responsive mobile menu is triggered?